# Error Number: 1052 Column 'site_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: bug, files, core

We are getting the above error on an intranet that is running the following code:

```
{exp:file:entries category_group="2" category="<?= $cat; ?>"}
    <tr>
        <td class="date">{entry_date format="%m/%d/%Y"}</td>
        <td class="title"><a href="{file_url}">{title}</a></td>
        <td class="description">{description}</td>
    </tr>
{/exp:file:entries}
```

We are getting the following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   offset: 1 Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php Line Number: 1724
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   offset: 2 Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php Line Number: 1724
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   offset: 1 Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php Line Number: 1724
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   offset: 2 Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php Line Number: 1724
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   offset: 1 Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php Line Number: 1724
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   offset: 2 Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php Line Number: 1724
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: Cannot modify
>   header information - headers already sent by (output started at
>   /home/national/public_html/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
>   Filename: core/Common.php Line Number: 446
>
> Error Number: 1052 Column 'site_id' in where clause is ambiguous
>   SELECT `exp_files`.`file_id`, `variable_name`, `variable_data` FROM
>   (`exp_files`, `exp_global_variables`) INNER JOIN `exp_file_categories`
>   ON `exp_files`.`file_id` = `exp_file_categories`.`file_id` INNER JOIN
>   `exp_categories` ON `exp_file_categories`.`cat_id` =
>   `exp_categories`.`cat_id` WHERE `exp_files`.`site_id` IN ('1') AND
>   `exp_categories`.`cat_id` = '1' AND `exp_categories`.`cat_id` = '2'
>   AND `site_id` = '1' Filename: libraries/Template.php Line Number: 2989

This is after an upgrade from EE 2.4 to EE 2.8.1. Not sure what to try... support hasn't responded in over 24 hours. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the heads up, Robson.  I'm pretty sure they're running into this bug:

https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20414

It's fixed up for the next release.

Those weird queries can happen if the query cache isn't cleared out when it should be.